# Check CRM form field value Empty or Not

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I want to check CRM form fields value empty or not at C# plugin code.

```
Entity ent; 

if(ent.Attributes["telephone2"].ToString()==string.Empty)
{
   Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

**ent.Attributes["telephone2"].ToString()** this is throwing KeyNotFoundException when **telephone2** field's value is empty. Now I need to check the value of **telephone2** before it throws exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
Entity contact = new Entity("contact");
if (contact.Contains("telephone2") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.GetAttributeValue<string>("telephone2"))
{
    // telephone 2 is not null
}
```

Edit: More information to justify this brief answer

I've found that there is a difference between `null` and `empty`

Imagine this scenario:

- You have an update plugin on Contact.
- This Contact has First Name ("John") and Last Name ("Smith") set
- You Update the First Name

Now, when you read the input parameters using `GetAttributeValue`, you won't know if the Last Name attribute is null, or if it is an empty string. Hence the need to check whether `entity.attributes` contains Last Name

```
Entity contact = pluginContext.InputParameters["Target"] as Entity;
var lastName = contact.getAttribute<string>("lastname");
// -> lastName is an empty string

var lastNameInInputParameters = contact.Contains("lastname");
// -> lastNameInInputParameters is false
```

If an attribute is null in the InputParameters this doesn't mean that the attribute has a null value, **it just means that the user hasn't changed this field in this update**

Comment: I've updated my answer to include more information about why I use this approach

Answer (score 3):

The preferred way of getting field values from entities is using the `GetAttributeValue<T>` method.

In Dynamics CRM the system never returns `null` or `string.Empty` values, so checking for these values when the attribute *is* present serves no purpose. Just read values like this:

```
string phoneNumber = ent.GetAttributeValue<string>("telephone2");

if (phoneNumber != null)
{
   // do something...
}
```

Comment: I've found that there is a difference between `null` and `empty` For example if you have an update plugin on Contact. If you read the input parameters using `GetAttributeValue`, you won't know if the attribute is null, or if the value of the attribute is an empty string. Hence the need to check whether `entity.attributes` contains this attribute

Comment: @jasonscript: That's correct. The Target entity that is present in the InputParameters collection is not returned by querying the system, but represents the user's input. Here strings can be set to `null` by setting the attribute's value to `null` or to an empty string. Likewise `EntityReference` attributes can be set to `null` or to an `EntityReference` instance with a `Guid.Empty` value.

Answer (score 1):

The below code snippet can be helpful. I have a plugin which validates a field "ita_notestallowedmessage" on create and update of entity "ita_trainingconfiguration" record to check whether the field is null or not. In my case after creating the record with some value in "ita_notestallowedmessage" field, if I update the value of field "ita_notestallowedmessage" to null then in input parameters I get Empty string instead of null. So it is a good idea to check String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) instead of only checking null in these type of scenarios.

```
if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {
                Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
                if (entity.LogicalName != "ita_trainingconfiguration")
                    return;
                if (!entity.Contains("ita_notestallowedmessage") && context.MessageName == "Create" && context.MessageName != "Update")
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("No test allowed can not be null");
                if(entity.Contains("ita_notestallowedmessage") && context.MessageName == "Update")
                {
                    var value = entity.GetAttributeValue<string>("ita_notestallowedmessage");
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                        throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("value of no test allowed field should not be null");
                }
            }
```